# Numerical simulation for a bounded process. Is slight deviation a "normal" fact?

Tags: numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, simulation, numerical-calculus

Suppose I have to numerically simulate a process $\{y_t\}$ such that $y_t\geq0$ $\forall t\in\mathbb{N}$, with $t$ denoting time-step.
Let's suppose I use MonteCarlo with $\mathscr{N}$ simulation trajectories. Could it occur that sometimes, when running simulation, some of these $\mathscr{N}$ trajectories slightly goes beyond $0$ hence violating the condition of non-negativity of the process?
 I mean: should I take this fact as an alert around the incorrectness of my simulation code or is it allowed that numerical simulation can (**just "sometimes"**) give you some trajectories (out of the total $\mathscr{N}$) that slightly deviate from the non-negativity condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further information, if you know (via proof or definition) that your process cannot take on negative values for all possible values in your domain, then there's an error in your code. The alternative is that you've overlooked something in your analysis.

Comment: Specifically, I refer to CIR model implementation via Euler method. It is quite simple to implement, hence it seems strange to me that some error is in place in my code. However, in some simulation, some trajectories out of the total number of trajectories goes slightly beyond $0$ and I cannot understand why, that's the point @PrasannaMaddila

Comment: Found this article that says that it may be because of discretisation error. ( cf. Section 2.1 ) : http://lnu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1270329/FULLTEXT01.pdf . It also details how to counter it, so it looks like you're on the right track! :-)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you a lot for this reference :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Have fun! :-)